# Best way to get friends interaction whit my app (php or java)

Tags: java, php, mysql, facebook

I need to find the fastest or best way to get all the interactions (that are stored in my DB) of the friends of the current user to show them like a news feed.

I started whith the fql call:

```
select uid, name, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user=1
```

and then a query to my db, searching all the rows that have some of those ids. The problem is that it's very slow.

My db call:

```
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
    $lista = $lista.", ".$friend['id'];
}

$sql = "SELECT resp FROM respuestas WHERE de OR para IN (".$lista.") LIMIT 5";`
```

The respuestas table structure:

```
+---+------+------------+-------+----------------+--------+
| 1 |  id  | int(11)    | INDEX | AUTO_INCREMENT | UNIQUE |
+---+------+------------+-------+----------------+--------+
| 2 | de   | bigint(20) | INDEX |                |        |
+---+------+------------+-------+----------------+--------+    
| 3 | para | bigint(20) | INDEX |                |        |
+---+------+------------+-------+----------------+--------+
| 4 | resp | text       |       |                |        |
+---+------+------------+-------+----------------+--------+
```

The query searches for all the rows that content any friend of the user in 'de' or 'para'.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: It's unlikely to be PHP or Java being slow, more likely to be the database search.... show your table structures (and indexes), all your queries, and an EXPLAIN of those queries

Comment: Youre right, i edited.

Comment: `WHERE de OR para IN (".$lista.")` is that really what you mean? Or are do you mean `WHERE de IN (".$lista.") OR para IN (".$lista.")`

Comment: WHERE de IN (".$lista.") OR para IN (".$lista.")

Comment: @dachi I appreciate that you're trying to help by editing all these posts, but there are a few other problems in most of the posts that you suggested edits for. In the future, please improve everything you can in a post before suggesting an edit. As an example, see my edit.